# How to use UCKeyTranslate

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift, core-services

Given a key-code for a key pressed without modifiers, I want to produce the result of pressing the shift+key. Example: For a standard US keyboard <shift>+<period> gives >.

The relevant function is UCKeytranslate, but I need a bit of help getting the details right. The snippet below is a full program ready to run in Xcode. The intent of the program is given <period> to produce the character >.

The result of the program is:

```
Keyboard: <TSMInputSource 0x10051a930> KB Layout: U.S. (id=0)
Layout: 0x0000000102802000
Status: -50
UnicodeString: 97
String: a
Done
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

The part that gets the layout seems to be working, but the status code reveals that something went wrong. But what?

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa
import Carbon
import AppKit

// The current text input source (read keyboard) has a layout in which
// we can lookup how key-codes are resolved.

// Get the a reference keyboard using the current layout.
var unmanagedKeyboard = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardLayoutInputSource()
var keyboard = unmanagedKeyboard.takeUnretainedValue() as TISInputSource
print("Keyboard: ") ; println(keyboard)

// Get the layout
var ptrLayout   = TISGetInputSourceProperty(keyboard, kTISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData)
var layout = UnsafeMutablePointer<UCKeyboardLayout>(ptrLayout)
print("Layout: "); println(layout)

// Let's see what the result of pressing  <shift> and <period>  (hopefully the result is > )
var keycode             = UInt16(kVK_ANSI_Period)                           // Keycode for <period>
var keyaction           = UInt16(kUCKeyActionDisplay)                       // The user is requesting information for key display
var modifierKeyState    = UInt32(1 << 17)                                   // Shift
var keyboardType        = UInt32(LMGetKbdType())
var keyTranslateOptions = UInt32(1 << kUCKeyTranslateNoDeadKeysBit)
var deadKeyState        = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>(bitPattern: 0)       // Is 0 the correct value?
var maxStringLength     = UniCharCount(4)                                   // uint32
var actualStringLength  = UnsafeMutablePointer<UniCharCount>.alloc(1)       //
actualStringLength[0]=16
var unicodeString       = UnsafeMutablePointer<UniChar>.alloc(255)
unicodeString[0] = 97 // a (this value is meant to be overwritten by UCKeyTranslate)
var str = NSString(characters: unicodeString, length: 1)
var result = UCKeyTranslate(layout, keycode, keyaction, modifierKeyState, keyboardType, keyTranslateOptions,
                            deadKeyState, maxStringLength, actualStringLength, unicodeString)

// Print the results
print("Status: "); println(result)
var unichar = unicodeString[0];
print("UnicodeString: "); println(String(unichar))
print("String: "); println(str)
println("Done")
```

EDIT

I have rewritten the snippet following the suggestions of Ken Thomases.
A few tricks from: [Graphite](https://github.com/sdegutis/DIY-Window-Manager/blob/e0ddd9e0f97a039455b090729b5c6123adb1c08d/Graphite/Graphite/Keycode.swift#L37) a Swift program using keycodes was also used.

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa
import Carbon
import AppKit

// The current text input source (read keyboard) has a layout in which
// we can lookup how key-codes are resolved.

// Get the a reference keyboard using the current layout.
let keyboard = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource().takeRetainedValue()
let rawLayoutData = TISGetInputSourceProperty(keyboard, kTISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData)
print("Keyboard: ") ; println(keyboard)

// Get the layout
var layoutData      = unsafeBitCast(rawLayoutData, CFDataRef.self)
var layout: UnsafePointer<UCKeyboardLayout> = unsafeBitCast(CFDataGetBytePtr(layoutData), UnsafePointer<UCKeyboardLayout>.self)
print("Layout: "); println(layout)

print("KbdType "); println(LMGetKbdType()) // Sanity check (prints 44)

var keycode             = UInt16(kVK_ANSI_Period)                         // Keycode for a
var keyaction           = UInt16(kUCKeyActionDisplay)
var modifierKeyState    = UInt32(1 << 1)                                  // Shift
var keyboardType        = UInt32(LMGetKbdType())
var keyTranslateOptions = OptionBits(kUCKeyTranslateNoDeadKeysBit)
var deadKeyState        = UInt32(0)                                       // Is 0 the correct value?
var maxStringLength     = UniCharCount(4)                                 // uint32
var chars: [UniChar]    = [0,0,0,0]
var actualStringLength  = UniCharCount(1)
var result = UCKeyTranslate(layout, keycode, keyaction, modifierKeyState, keyboardType, keyTranslateOptions,
                            &deadKeyState, maxStringLength, &actualStringLength, &chars)
// Print the results
print("Status: "); println(result)
print("Out:"); println(UnicodeScalar(chars[0]))
println("Done")
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `Use of undeclared type 'UCKeyboardLayout'` with this code. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The docs for 10.10.3 says the struct `UCKeyboardLayout` was removed. You need to look what replaced it. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_10_3/modules/CoreServices.html

Comment: PS: I tried looking it up, but the docs for UCKeyboardLayout doesn't mention Swift at all now: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Unicode_Utilities_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UCKeyboardLayout

Comment: PPS: Others have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531871/xcode-6-3-swift-unicode-utilities-e-g-uckeytranslate-is-not-available

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For `kTISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData`, `TISGetInputSourceProperty()` returns a `CFDataRef`. You need to get its bytes pointer and treat that as the pointer to `UCKeyboardLayout`. I don't think that's what you're doing with this line:

```
var layout = UnsafeMutablePointer<UCKeyboardLayout>(ptrLayout)
```

I don't really know Swift, but it would probably work as:

```
var layout = UnsafePointer<UCKeyboardLayout>(CFDataGetBytePtr(ptrLayout))
```

or maybe:

```
var layout = CFDataGetBytePtr(ptrLayout) as UnsafePointer<UCKeyboardLayout>
```

Also, `kUCKeyActionDisplay` is mostly useless. Its intent is to return the label of the key, but it doesn't even do that reliably. You probably want to use `kUCKeyActionDown`.

For the modifiers, you want to use the Carbon-era `shiftKey` bit mask shifted right 8 bits (as shown in the documentation for `UCKeyTranslate()`). `shiftKey` is `1 << 9`, so `shiftKey >> 8` is `1 << 1`.

For the options, you should be able to use `kUCKeyTranslateNoDeadKeysMask` for simplicity. It's equivalent to `1 << kUCKeyTranslateNoDeadKeysBit`.

Yes, 0 is the proper value for `deadKeyState` for an initial keystroke or one where you don't want to apply any previous dead-key state.

I'm not sure why you've commented the `maxStringLength` line with `uint32`. That type is completely unrelated to the maximum string length. `maxStringLength` is the maximum number of UTF-16 code units (what the APIs incorrectly call "characters") the `UCKeyTranslate()` should write to the provided buffer. It's basically the buffer size, measured in `UniChar`s (not bytes). In your case it should be 255. Or, since you probably don't expect to get 255 "characters" from a single keystroke, you could reduce the size of the buffer and set `maxStringLength` to match whatever it is.

Your handling of `str` is strange. You construct it from the `unicodeString` buffer before calling `UCKeyTranslate()`. Do you expect that string object's value to be changed because `UCKeyTranslate()` changes the contents of `unicodeString`? It does not. If it did, that would be a very bad bug in `NSString`. You should construct the `NSString` from the buffer **after** `UCKeyTranslate()` has successfully populated that buffer. Of course, you should pass `actualStringLength` as the length parameter when constructing the `NSString`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I feel I am getting closer to a solution - I just need to crack the CFDataGetBytePtr problem. The reason for the uint32 comment is that I am writing bindings for UCKeyTranslate and need the underlying C type. The Swift program is to get a working example I can mimick with the FFI.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer.