# Xcode 6.3 and Swift: Unicode Utilities (e.g. UCKeyTranslate) are not available?

Tags: xcode, swift, unicode

I have the following test code:

```
import Cocoa
import Carbon
let x = kUCKeyActionDisplay
```

In Xcode 6.2 there is no problem, but in Xcode 6.3 this code throws an error.

The error message is: `Use of unresolved identifier 'kUCKeyActionDisplay'`.

Why can't I access the `UnicodeUtilities` namespace?

Comment: `let x = kUCKeyActionDisplay` compiles without problems in my Xcode 8.1 if you `import Carbon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no longer available in Swift for some reason, according to the [OSX 10.10.3 API documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_10_3/modules/CoreServices.html).

You can however still access them in Objective-C, in the same way (i.e. `@import CoreServices;`)

I've just written the code that needs them in Objective-C - you could of course create a wrapper.