# Can the ObjC function UCKeyTranslate be used from JavaScript for Automation?

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript, javascript-automation

In an osascript/JXA context, I need to map macOS keyCodes and modifiers to Unicode strings (for any keyboard layout, specified at run-time)

The obvious candidate appears to be `UCKeyTranslate`, but my attempts to get a reference to it from a JavaScript for Automation context have not been successful so far.

Does anybody know how to do this, perhaps in terms of `ObjC.bindFunction` ?

---

When ObjC libraries are imported into the 'JavaScript for Automation' (or 'JXA') JSContext, a global `$` symbol is decorated with their methods.

So, for example, evaluating `$.NSPasteboard` in a vanilla JXA context evaluates to undefined, but after `ObjC.import('Appkit')`, we can write, and successfully evaluate, expressions like:

```
ObjC.deepUnwrap(
    $.NSPasteboard
    .generalPasteboard
    .propertyListForType(clipType)
);
```

In this case however, `$.UCKeyTranslate` remains undefined in the JSContext after:

```
ObjC.import("CoreServices")
ObjC.import("CarbonCore")
```

In such cases we can sometimes bind the names of ObjC functions to a JSContext name using `ObjC.bindFunction`, for example, although it would be redundant, we could successfully write and make use of the names function names 'sin' and 'cos' after writing.

```
['sin', 'cos'].forEach(
    k => ObjC.bindFunction(k, ['double', ['double']]));
```

In this case, however, neither the ObjC.import nor ObjC.bindFunction routes have so far defined the name `$.UCKeyTranslate` or `UCKeyTranslate` in the JXA JSContext.

Comment: What is the criticism of the question ?  A real and useful issue in macOS scripting, and very happy to expand.

Comment: You mention not being successful, but what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go would be to make a Swift or ObjC helper library (or a command line tool), and then use that from JXA. [Check some example code to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735217/how-to-use-uckeytranslate).

If you wrap this call in an ObjC object method inside a framework, it's possible to `ObjC.import()` it and use in your scripts. If you choose to do a command line app, then call it as a shell command.

Using ObjC.bindFunction seems a bit too complicated, because you'd have to bind a few other functions that would get you a UCKeyboardLayout instance, and define a bunch of magic constants, plus do some necessary mapping of strings and pointers.

Comment: That's a useful link, and includes a reference to what appears to be a withdrawal of the function from macOS, despite its continued appearance in their online documentation:

[CoreServices Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_10_3/modules/CoreServices.html)